# How to connect to the same network and same subnet with two interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routes

In Lab we have two hosts say A and B.
host A has two NIC and host B has single NIC (see below diagram for network topology)

NIC-1 of host A is connected to lab network and

NIC-2 of host A is connected directly (end-to-end) to host B

```
            ----------
            |         | -> NIC1                  ------> Lab Network (10.203.194.0/24)
            |         |    (eth0 - 10.203.194.247/24)
            | host A  |                                          ----------
            |         | -> NIC2                  -------> NIC1   | host B  | 
            -----------   (eth1 - 10.203.209.230/24)             -----------
                                                             (eth0 - 10.203.194.163/24)
```

From host A, I was able to ping 'lab network' whereas I couldn't connect/ping host B (10.203.194.163). I find a routing table of host A has default gw to lab network.

What changes were required to connect Lab network and host B FROM host A.

I can go for a bridge connection connecting both eth0 and eth1 interface in host A; but I don't prefer that option because host B should not recieve any packet specific to lab network and that is the reason I did not connect host B directly to lab network.

I am looking for some routing option that is specific to the destination/source and the interface has to be decided based on that.

Comment: Make a bridge interface on host A that bridges NIC1 and NIC2 and put the 10.203.194.247/24 on that bridge interface.

Comment: please kindly look into this http://ramu492.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-make-linux-machine-as.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue by simply adding the rule in the route table.

$>route add –host 10.203.194.163 dev eth1

and  now my routing table looks like:

```
 Destination      Gateway       Genmask         Flags MSS Windows irtt Iface
 10.203.194.163   0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 UH    0   0       0    eth1
 10.203.194.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U     0   0       0    eth0
 0.0.0.0          10.203.194.1  0.0.0.0         UG    0   0       0    eth0
```

and when I ping from host B to host A and running tcpdump on eth0, I won't get any ICMP packets and in eth1 I can see all ICMP packets from host B :)